# How to update sql data in this condition?

Tags: mysql

i have table like this

| user_id | name | age | genre | target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0000001 | Roy | 17 | M | X |
| 0000002 | Fina | 21 | F | X |

and i create new column in another table and want to move "target" column's value to that table

| user_id | colum_a | target |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0000001 | aaaaaaa |  |
| 0000002 | aaaaaaa |  |

please tell me how to use sql update to move the target value to Table 2 ? Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Anything not working with a `UPDATE` query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `user_id` is `unique`:

```
UPDATE tbl2 
SET target = (SELECT target FROM tbl1 WHERE tbl1.user_id = tbl2.user_id)
```

**UPDATE:**
You can also do it with `join`:

```
UPDATE tbl2 
JOIN tbl1 ON tbl2.user_id = tbl1.user_id
SET tbl2.target = tbl1.target
```